# Equilateral triangle with points on the sides

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

On the sides $AB$ and $AC$ of the equilateral triangle $ABC$ points $E$ and $D$ are chosen such that $\dfrac{BE}{EA}=\dfrac{AD}{DC}=\dfrac12$. Segments $BD$ and $CE$ intersect at $P$. Show that $\measuredangle APC=90^\circ$.

The problem is under the lesson on a dot product of vectors. One of the theorems states that two nonzero vectors are perpendicular if and only if their dot product is equal to $0$. How can we use this? Thanks! I cannot choose a proper vector base with which to express the vectors.

Comment: Set $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$, $C=(1/2,\sqrt3/2)$ and go on.

Answer (score 1):

Let position vectors of the vertices be $\vec{A}$, $\vec{B}$, $\vec{C}$ (with origin somewhere in the plane). Now you can apply section formula and take dot products etc.

For example position vectors of $D,E$ will be given by
$$\vec{D}=\frac{2}{3}\vec{A}+\frac{1}{3}\vec{C} \quad , \quad \vec{E}=\frac{1}{3}\vec{A}+\frac{2}{3}\vec{B}$$

You can find position vector of $P$ by writing it in two ways since it belongs to $BD$ and $CE$, using section formula.

After that you need to show $$(\vec{C}-\vec{P})\cdot (\vec{A}-\vec{P})=0$$

That said, synthetic solution also exists to show $\angle APC=90^{\circ}$.